# Moment utc timezone removal

Tags: javascript, date, timezone, momentjs, utc

I have a moment date that's displayed in the console as

```
Moment<2022-11-04T20:45:35+02:00>
```

I want to regardless of the browser, remove this utc adjustment and always have the date as

```
Moment<2022-11-04T20:45:35+00:00>
```

with the +02:00, replaced by +00:00

I have tried using utcOffset, utc and to iso string, still it's not displaying as I desire

Comment: Sounds like your just wanting to deal with UTC dates, try using `moment.utc(...)`

Comment: Those two timestamps are two hours apart, not the same moment in time.  You'd have to replace the offset *and* also adjust the time value.  Also you didn't provide any code, so it's unclear what sort of answer you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not exactly sure what would be the use case of your question but you can do that by manually adjusting the timezone offset.

Like this:

```js
const timeStr = '2022-11-04T20:45:35+04:00'
const time = moment(timeStr)

// get the offset from the time string
const offset = timeStr.slice(-6)

// set the timezone offset (so that in case it doesn't match your local time, it's corrected)
time.utcOffset(offset)

// add the offset time, and convert to UTC
time.add(time.utcOffset(), 'minutes').utc()
console.log(time)
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but this gave me the same with the +02:00 hours in the string

Comment: after adjusting time, you can set the timezone to UTC to get it displayed in UTC.

Comment: Lots of things wrong here.  1) Adding time will represent a different moment in time, not adjust for time zone. 2) The moment object created will be in local time, so the offset returned by `utcOffset()` is not necessarily the 2 hours in the input string.  3) Moment objects are mutable, so you're changing both `time` and `adjustedTime`. 4) By logging the moment object directly instead of formatting it, you're just going see a timestamp in UTC (in most environments).

Comment: 1) that's what the OP asked.

Comment: 2) you're right. I'll update the answer. 3) good catch. I updated the answer. 4) logging was just for demoing the actual change, not necessarily part of the answer but updated the time to be in UTC timezone anyway.